# How do I get a variable from another class?

Tags: python, class, oop, variables

I have the following class:

```
class Login():
    #PROMPT THE OPERATOR TO LOGIN
    def login(self):
        self.usr = input("usr> ")
        self.pwd = getpass.getpass("pwd> ")
        self.check_login()
```

I also have this class:

```
class Kernel(Login):
    #THIS IS WHERE THE OPERATOR CAN ENTER STUFF AND SHIT.
    def kernel(self):
        obj = Login()
        kernel_input = input(obj.login.self.usr + "@" + OS_NAME.lower() + ">")
```

However, I have no idea how to get the variable *self.usr* from the class *Login* to work on the class *Kernel* which is a child to the class *Login*.

As you can see, I have created the Login() object and stored it into the variable *obj*. In the Login class, there is a method called *login* which holds a self variable called *usr*.

I tried calling it in another class using:

```
obj.usr
obj.self.usr
obj.login.usr
obj.login.self.usr
```

But none of that works.
How could I make this work?

Comment: It seems odd to be creating an instance of Login() inside an instance of Kernel, when Kernel already subclasses Login (so it has all the same methods and attributes as a Login instance, without having to call Login()

Comment: Base classes are normally an "is-a" relationship.  A `Kernel` is a `Login`??  Instead, `Kernel` should have a `login` method.

Comment: Agree with Mark here. Odd design style :)

Answer (score 1):

`obj.usr` is the correct way.  However, that attribute will not exist until after the `login` method of the `Login` object is called.  You would need to do something like:

```
obj = Login()
obj.login()
# now you can use obj.usr
```

It's hard to know exactly when you should be calling `login()` without knowing exactly how your classes are meant to be used (e.g., when the Login object's login is "supposed" to happen).  Another possibility is that you actually want to set `usr` and `pwd` during the Login class's `__init__`, so they exist as soon as the object is created.

Answer (score 0):

the `usr` attribute is only set when you call the `login` method. You'll need to call that for the attribute to be set with `obj.login()`. Then you can access it with `obj.usr`.

Based on the fact that Kernel is a subclass of `Login`, there's probably no benefit of making another `Login` object in the `kernel` method, you could call `self.login()` and `self.usr`.

Also, I'm guessing you might be coming from another language where a method with the same name of the class is the constructor? That's not the case in Python, the constructor is called `__init__`.

Answer (score -1):

create a globally defined dict. ex:

```
mydict = dict()
class Login():
    #PROMPT THE OPERATOR TO LOGIN
    def login(self):
        self.usr = input("usr> ")
        self.pwd = getpass.getpass("pwd> ")
        mydict.update({'password':self.pwd, 'user': self.usr})
        self.check_login()

class Kernel(Login):
    #THIS IS WHERE THE OPERATOR CAN ENTER STUFF AND SHIT.
    def kernel(self):
        kernel_input = input(mydict['user'] + "@" + OS_NAME.lower() + ">")
```